# If value in serial begin is greater than that of delay in arduino, does delay time matters?

Tags: arduino

I think if the value inside `Serial.begin()` is greater than the value inside `delay()`,then delay will not take the next step as soon as the next input is there ...

**Question:**
The `delay()` function is insignificant...no?

Comment: Why do you believe the baud rate of the serial port and the value given to the `delay` function are related?

Comment: Also why have you tagged this with raspberry-pi when it appears to be about Arduino?

Comment: @mttrb consider editing to remove irrelevant tags. Clearly OP is new here.

Comment: I'm with @mttrb here, the baudrate has very little to do with delay. Your question does not make a whole lot of sense. Please post some of your code and try to clarify your question.